# How to compile and use Netgen (network generator)?

Tags: c, makefile

I want to use [Netgen](ftp://dimacs.rutgers.edu/pub/netflow/generators/network/netgen/) - a generator for capacitated networks. But I've got two problems:

If I run `make` then I get the following error:

```
cc -O -DDIMACS   -c -o netgen.o netgen.c
In file included from netgen.c:86:0:
netgen.h:45:6: error: conflicting types for ‘random’
 long random(long, long);      /* generate random integer in interval */
      ^
In file included from netgen.h:31:0,
                 from netgen.c:86:
/usr/include/stdlib.h:321:17: note: previous declaration of ‘random’ was here
 extern long int random (void) __THROW;
                 ^
netgen.c: In function ‘main’:
netgen.c:522:11: warning: format ‘%ld’ expects argument of type ‘long int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
    printf("n %ld\n", i + 1);
           ^
netgen.c:535:11: warning: format ‘%ld’ expects argument of type ‘long int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
    printf("n %ld s\n", i + 1);
           ^
netgen.c:538:11: warning: format ‘%ld’ expects argument of type ‘long int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
    printf("n %ld t\n", i + 1);
           ^
netgen.c:550:11: warning: format ‘%ld’ expects argument of type ‘long int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
    printf("n %ld %ld\n", i + 1, B[i]);
           ^
netgen.c:553:9: warning: format ‘%ld’ expects argument of type ‘long int’, but argument 4 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
  printf("a %ld %ld %ld %ld %ld\n", FROM[i], TO[i], 0, U[i], C[i]);
         ^
<builtin>: recipe for target 'netgen.o' failed
make: *** [netgen.o] Error 1
```

I know the conflict is a result of using `stdlib.h` and `random.c` - how can I fix this?

The second problem is that I don't know how to use the problem sets (for example `problems.8` and `problems.40` (see link above))

Thank you in advance!

Comment: "how can I fix this?" ...Don't use libraries that are sloppy enough to define symbols clashing with the stdlib? More practically, you have the files, so if you need to, you can rename the `netgen` function(s) to avoid clashes. But then, back to the sloppy library, it's invoking UB by using the wrong specifier for `printf`, so you have more problems to solve. Anyway, since it hasn't been updated since around 1993, (A) compiling as an older C version might help, & (B) I think you're safe to fix it up for your own use. If licence permits, you could even publish your own fork with much better code

Comment: I know the generator is more than 40 years old but it is still in use. I have to verify some data based on Netgen - that's the reason why I have to use it.  You both gave me the hint to make the make-file older - that worked fine (just received some warnings: `warning: format ‘%ld’ expects argument of type ‘long int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]`). But how can I use the executable file to generate some networks? What have to be entered into the terminal?